# How to run a simple hello world application using mean.io

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I am new (few hours into it)to mean stack development.I was starting up with documentation in mean.io website .Here I am confused how / where to run helloworld.js from?
localhost:3000 gives mean home page
I have just a static html page with alert box showing hello world 
how to run this ??
For Example in case of wamp inside of www folder .So from where or how a application can be run?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you are new to mean.io stack or an experienced user, this tutorial series will help you learn how to use mean.io

through them you will develop an application that will allow us to manage our goals:

1. [Part-1](https://codewithintent.com/mean-io-tutorial-building-goals-application-from-scratch-part-1/)
2. [Part-2](https://codewithintent.com/mean-io-tutorial-building-goals-application-from-scratch-part-2/)
3. [Part-3](https://codewithintent.com/mean-io-tutorial-building-goals-application-from-scratch-part-3/)
4. [Part-4](https://codewithintent.com/mean-io-tutorial-building-a-goals-application-from-scratch-part-4/)
5. [Part-5](https://codewithintent.com/mean-io-tutorial-part-5-integrating-ghost-with-mean/)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is using [Bitnami MEAN](https://bitnami.com/stack/mean). Gives you an environment where you can start with.

Comment: I want to know how to set up the environment from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of the full-stack scaffolding framework.

It's a scaffolding framework that gets you started with the MEAN Stack with one quick command.

```
sudo npm install full-stack -g
full-stack init myProject
```

You can learn more about the tool here: https://www.meanstack.net/